# WP8 No Such a table Sqlite

Tags: windows-phone-8

i m trying to develop windows phone application but i have a problem about sqlite. I couldn't connect database and app. I had error message like this "no such table: hastalik". If some 1 have any idea, please share. Thanks for your help.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Storage;
using SQLite;

namespace illnessTracker
{
    public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        public static string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "ilac.sqlite"));
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=ilac.sqlite; FailIfMissing=True"))
            {

                // Create a new task.
                hastalik hasta = new hastalik();
                hasta.hastalikAdi = txtbxHastalikAdi.Text;
                hasta.semptomlar = txtbxSemptomlar.Text;
                hasta.ilaclar = tbxIlaclar.Text;
                hasta.not = tbxNot.Text;
                hasta.doktorTavsiyesi = tbxTavsiye.Text;
                hasta.tarihi = DateTime.Now.Date;

                /// Insert the new task in the Task table.
                dbConn.Insert(hasta);
            }
        }
        [Table("hastalik")]
        public class hastalik
        {
            [Column("hastalikID")]
            [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
            public int hastalikID { get; set; }

            [Column("hastalikAdi")]
            public string hastalikAdi { get; set; }
            [Column("semptomlar")]
            public string semptomlar { get; set; }
            [Column("ilaclar")]
            public string ilaclar { get; set; }
            [Column("doktorTavsiyesi")]
            public string doktorTavsiyesi { get; set; }
            [Column("not")]
            public string not { get; set; }
            [Column("tarihi")]
            public DateTime tarihi { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you created an initial database with that table in it?

Comment: Yes, my database name is ilac.sqlite . I have 2 table in the my db which name is hasta and hastalik .

Comment: Your error message is telling you that the table doesn't exist. I also can't see any code that will check for it's existence and create as required, nor read your file.

Comment: i created my tables in sqlite manager. Am i need to create my table again in my code?